# Test $_POST variable array before use

Tags: php

I usually test $_POST variable values before I use them, which works fine.  However; now that the $_POST variable is an array I have run into a problem.  I have a set of 6 check boxes that all use the same name array.  After a submit and if validation errors are found, I want to remember and set these check boxes.  So I tried using the same format I have used for other fields but this time I get a syntax error and the page doesn't display.  This is the code I tried:

`<?php if(isset($_POST["projectOptions"])) && if(in_array('socialMedia', $_POST["projectOptions"])) echo ' checked="checked"';?>`

and this is the error I get:

`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_BOOLEAN_AND`.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?  Or, if this is not the correct way then please show me the correct way.

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: Count `)` and `(` And read about `if` syntax.

Comment: also, do your checkboxes have `name="projectOptions[]"` using brackets?

Comment: @u_mulder According to my count all ( and ) match.

Comment: @u_mulder According to my count all ( and ) match.

Comment: see both answers below; all correct and your use of `&& if(in_array` is incorrect.

Comment: @Fred -ii Yes, exactly as shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proper syntax for multiple statements in `if` is the following:

```
if ($a && $b)
```

Syntax

```
if ($a) && if ($b)
```

is **invalid**.

Finally:

```
if(isset($_POST["projectOptions"]) && in_array('socialMedia', $_POST["projectOptions"])) 
    echo ' checked="checked"';
```

Comment: So, I guess their `&& if(in_array` should read as `&& (in_array` then, correct? edit: not based on Martin's answer. I just saw it pop up now lol

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["projectOptions"]) && in_array('socialMedia', $_POST["projectOptions"])){
 echo ' checked="checked"';
}
?>
```

- You should Combine `If` clauses without closing the bracket `)`. IF all are true the `if` statement is `TRUE` and executes.

I have slightly expanded out the code above for clarity.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I'm brain dead today.  But, u_mulder get the check mark because he was first.

Comment: @CharlesEF no worries, I saw his answer appear as I was writing mine. Brain dead hours happen to us all, and it's good to get a new set of eyes on a confusion.